# Yadcf integrate with Meteor simple schema

Tags: mongodb, meteor, database-schema, yadcf, meteor-orion

I want to filter column header data from my tabular table.

My goal is to filter:

1. Numbers (greater than, equal etc...)
2. Strings
3. Dates

as in the following example

[image: filters]

Thus  I want to integrate the filters of [yadcf](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/DOM_source.html) with my [tabular table](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-tabular) by using the [Orion](http://www.orionjs.org/) schema, by I can´t conclude,

> FIRST OPTION WITH SCHEMA
>
> Mi schema

```
Tickets = new orion.collection('tickets', {
  singularName: 'Tickets',
  pluralName: 'Tickets',
  title: 'Tickets',
  parentPath: '/admin',
  link: {title: 'Tickets', parent: '_template'},
  tabular: {
    scrollX: true,
    "processing": true,
    dom: 'lBfrtip',
    columns: [
      { data: "id", title: "ID" },
      { data: 'employeeName', title: 'Name' }
    ]
  }
});
Tickets.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
  id: { type: Number, label:'Id del Empleado', optional: true },
  employeeName: { type: String, label:'Name', optional: true }
}));

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish('get_Tickets', function() {return Tickets.find();});
};

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.subscribe('get_Tickets');
};
```

> My.html

```
{{> tabular table=collection.tabularTable class="table table-striped bordered" id=collection.pluralName }}
```

> SECOND OPTION WITH INSTANCE OF DATATABLE
>
> my.js

```
var TicketsTab=new Tabular.Table({
  name: 'Tickets',
  collection: Tickets,
  searching:true,
  columns: [
    {data: "id",title:"ID"},
    {data: "employeeName",title:"Name"}
  ]
});
var myTable = $('#TicketsTab').DataTable();
yadcf.init(myTable, [{column_number:0}]);
```

In this point I can´t conclude because I don´t know how to add .dataTable().yadcf([...]);